# How to create multiple different instaneces simillarly to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, oop

What I would like is to use `_h` like `$` jQuery. Every time I use `_h` i want to have new instance of Helper class, which would hold selected element, do stuff with them and so on.

The problem is that `_h` does not creates new instance of class, but rather use already created one.

I assumed if I use it like that:

```
var obj1 = _h('p');
var obj2 = _h('#testDiv');
```

I would have two different instances of class. However both instances store the same elements and seems to point to the same instance.

```
var _h = (function(){

    var Helper = function(query){

        if(window === this)
            return new Helper(query);

        this.Get.call(this, query);

        this._allCurrentElements = [];
    }

    Helper.prototype.Get = function(query){
        var els = document.querySelectorAll(query);
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            _allCurrentElements.push(els[i])
        };
        return this;
    }

    Helper.prototype.AddClass = function(cl) {
        // do stuff
        return this;
    }


    Helper.prototype.RemoveClass = function(cl) {
        // do stuff
        return this;
    }

    // more methods
    //return Helper;
    //return Helper();
    return new Helper();

})();
```

So if someone could point me that I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate that.

Edit: If I don't wrap it in IFFE, don't assign to _h var and call `var t = Helper('p')`, then it behaves as expected

Comment: Uh, you should not call `this.Get(query);` before you intialise `this._allCurrentElements = [];`. The method needs the array.

Comment: [Use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and your mistake will throw an exception.

Comment: Yeah, I know, just copied/pasted this, so it might be out of order :)

Comment: Well, we can only help you with the code you've posted, not the one you didn't show us. If it's not your actual code, please [edit] your question to fix c&p mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(function(){})()` is called an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Which means, you are declaring a anonymous function and invoking it in a single step. The return value of the IIFE is stored in `_h`.

When you return `new Helper();`, `_h` contains an instance of `Helper`.

When you return `Helper`, you are returning the constructor of the Helper class. You will have to use `new _h()` create new Helper object.

What you need is a wrapper function that will take the arguments, create a new Helper object and return it.

Try

```
var _h = (function(){

    var Helper = function(query){

        if(window === this)
            return new Helper(query);

        this.Get.call(this, query);

        this._allCurrentElements = [];
    }

    Helper.prototype.Get = function(query){
        var els = document.querySelectorAll(query);
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            _allCurrentElements.push(els[i])
        };
        return this;
    }

    Helper.prototype.AddClass = function(cl) {
        // do stuff
        return this;
    }


    Helper.prototype.RemoveClass = function(cl) {
        // do stuff
        return this;
    }

    // more methods

    return function (query) {
        return new Helper(query);
    };
})();
```

---

**Update 1**:

In `Helper.prototype.Get`, `_allCurrentElements` is a global variable. You need to use `this._allCurrentElements`.

Also, you need to initialize `this._allCurrentElements = [];` before calling `this.Get`

Working Example - https://jsfiddle.net/ucqgnbne/

**Update 2**

As @Bergi commented, returning Helper will work since you are using `if(window === this) return new Helper(query);`.

Comment: Just `return Helper` should suffice. It can even be called without `new` because of that (ugly and incorrect) `window == this` check.

Comment: Instead of using `this.Get.call(this, query);` , I did like in your fiddle `this.Get(query);` and worked like a charm. It seems, I was calling `Get()` on all my instances.  Thanks a lot  ;)

Comment: `this.Get.call(this, query)` and `this.Get(query)` are equivalent.